# How to set a HTTP Header Key/Value Pair within the MEAN Stack

Tags: javascript, angular, express, http-headers, mean-stack

I'm using the MEAN stack and need to set a HTTP header key/value pair within   my web app.

i.e. `my_key: my_value`

Using Angular 5 and found the following code:

```
app.use('/api', function (req, res) {
   let url = config.API_HOST + req.ur
    req.headers['someHeader'] = 'someValue'
    req.pipe(request(url)).pipe(res)
})
```

but unsure how to apply to my requirement as I believe the only line that I need from the above code is:

```
req.headers['my_key'] = 'my_value'
```

but not sure if I need the `req.pipe` line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use at least one middleware on npm for handling CORS in Express: [see @mscdex answer]

Set header field to value

```
res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
```

or pass an object to set multiple fields at once.

```
res.set({
  'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
  'Content-Length': '456'
})
```

Aliased as

```
res.header(field, [value])
```

for more information read the [Express documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html)